# Creating objects of same type as subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, types, subclass, superclass

I am designing a Genetic Algorithms library, and am currently constructing the `Genome` class. This class includes several methods for creating, mutating, crossing, and evaluating genomes, and will be central to this library. This abstract class has two subclasses `StaticGenome` and `VariableGenome`. These classes provide additional functionality for fixed or variable length genomes.

Ultimately, crossing any two genomes should be independent of the Genome Type. That being said, the method `singlePointCrossover(Genome parent2)` takes in two genomes, and returns a new `Genome` object, which is a special combination of the two parent genomes. However, because `Genome` is an abstract class, I cannot instantiate a new `Genome` object as it's offspring.

How can I return a new object of the same type as the subclass, from the superclass?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The `Genome` class:

```
public abstract class Genome <ElementType> {
    private String name;
    private List<AbstractGenomeElement<ElementType> > elements;

    // Mutation Methods //////////////////////////////////////////////
    public AbstractGenomeElement<ElementType> mutateElement(AbstractGenomeElement<Integer> element) {
        return this.mutateElementAtIndex(this.getElements().indexOf(element));
    }

    public AbstractGenomeElement<ElementType> mutateElementAtIndex(int i) {
        return this.getElement(i).mutate();
    }

    // Crossover Methods //////////////////////////////////////////////
    public Genome<ElementType> singlePointCrossover(Genome<ElementType> genome2){
        return multiPointCrossover(genome2, 1);
    }

    public Genome<ElementType> twoPointCrossover(Genome<ElementType> genome2){
        return multiPointCrossover(genome2, 2);
    }

    public Genome<ElementType> multiPointCrossover(Genome<ElementType> genome2, int crosses){
        List<AbstractGenomeElement<ElementType>> newElements= new ArrayList<AbstractGenomeElement<ElementType>>();
        Integer nums[] = new Integer[length-1];

        for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++) { nums[i] = i+1; }

        List<Integer> shuffled = Arrays.asList(nums);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        shuffled = shuffled.subList(0, crosses);
        boolean selectFromParentA = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(shuffled.contains((Integer)i)){
                selectFromParentA = !selectFromParentA;
            }
            if(selectFromParentA) newElements.add(this.getElement(i));
            else newElements.add(genome2.getElement(i));
        }
        // Code fails at this point. "Can not instantiate the type Genome"
        return new Genome<ElementType>(name, newElements);
    }
}
```

The two subclasses:

```
public class StaticGenome<ElementType> extends Genome<ElementType> {

}

public class VariableGenome<ElementType> extends Genome<ElementType> {

}
```

And the main method I am using for testing:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Genome<IntegerElement> genomeA = new StaticGenome<IntegerElement>("Genome A", 50);
    Genome<IntegerElement> genomeB = new StaticGenome<IntegerElement>("Genome B", 50);

    Genome<IntegerElement> offspring = genomeB.uniformCrossover(genomeA.elementCrossover(genomeA.multiPointCrossover(genomeB, 3)));
    offspring.setName("Offspring");
    System.out.println(offspring);
}
```

Comment: Reading the above post, i can see that genome can only be of 2 types StaticGenome and VariableGenome. Now when you want to return a genome, it will be of either of these 2 types. Is that correct?

Comment: I suppose, yes. At this moment, i don't have any other genome implementations in mind, but I can imagine that someone may want to create a new subclass `2DGenome` or something, with additional functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce the following method to the abstract class and implement it in the subclasses.

```
protected abstract Genome<ElementType> newInstance(String name, List<AbstractGenomeElement<ElementType>> elements);
```

when subclasses implement this they can return the correct instance. i.e: a new instance of their own kind. In your cross over method you could then call this method instead of doing 'new Genome'

Answer (score 1):

You can return a subclass from an overriden method, it's called co-variant return type

```
abstract class Genome {
    abstract Genome singlePointCrossover(Genome parent2); 
}

class StaticGenome extends Genome {
    @Override
    StaticGenome singlePointCrossover(Genome parent2) {
        ...
    }
}

class VariableGenome extends Genome {
    @Override
    VariableGenome singlePointCrossover(Genome parent2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, crossovers work the same, regardless of variable or static length. So I want to put that code in the `Genome` class so that I am not duplicating code

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html
"Unlike interfaces, abstract classes can contain fields that are not static and final, and they can contain implemented methods."
Make `Genome` an abstract class, but don't make `singlePointCrossover()` abstract.

Comment: yea, I just realized I missed your question completely (well the *actual* question), sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, the question is: given some `Genome` object (that will be some subclass of the abstract class `Genome`), how can we instantiate a new instance of that subclass?

Well, I don't know if this is the best way, but it's what I've come up with:

```
public Genome<ElementType> 
multiPointCrossover(Genome<ElementType> genome2, int crosses){
    // Snip...
    Genome g;
    try {
        g = genome2.getClass()
                .getConstructor(String.class, List.class)
                .newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Can throw quite a few exceptions...
    }
    return g;
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)

**Note:** I think Dev Blanked's solution is cleaner and simpler to work with. This is just what I came up with when they posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to introduce one more class in between Genome and Static/VariableGenome classes. I am not an expert of microbiology so cannot recommend a good logical name to it. But if you have a new child class(lets say newGenomeClass) of your Genome and acting as a Parent of your Static/VriablGenome classes then you can have your method like this:

```
public newGenomeClass singlePointCrossover(newGenomeClass parent1,newGenomeClass parent2).
```

Hope it helps!